# Google reCAPTCHA showing only when logged in to WordPress otherwise not

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have integrated reCAPTCHA on my contact form. I have congigured it properly by entreing the site key and the secret key. The problem is that the reCAPTCHA is showing only when I am logged in to WordPress and otherwise not.

The reCAPTCHA code is showing on Google Inspect only when I am logged in otherwise not.

Comment: Please put your code for contact form in your question

Comment: Did you find a solution? This has recently started happening on my website too.